# UIImagePickerController memory warnings

Tags: iphone, memory, warnings, uiimagepickercontroller

When having many data extensive apps running in the background (sometimes none), whenever I present the UIImagePickerController, i get a memory warning, usually between 1 and 2. I'm sure its not my code, because it i recieve that memory warning as soon as the camera view is presented. I'm keeping my instance of the UIImagePickerController in the app delegate (after reading countless articles). Anyone have any advice?

Comment: are you sure you are not testing on a jailbroken iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

A memory warning isn't a sign of a bug necessarily. Bringing up the image picker uses memory. If you're already running low, it'll trigger a warning. . Sounds like you need to be a little more careful with your ambient memory management? Or make sure you dump resources before you bring up the picker.

Comment: Could you please be more specific i.e. can you give any example with sample code?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, memory warnings happen. Don't fuss about it until apps start getting killed. Even then, it's only really a problem when the foreground app gets killed.

Of course, this doesn't discharge you from having to be as frugal with resources as you can - but sometimes there's just no way around it.